# Strange / wiered behaviour of NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I am sending a request (MySql Query in XML) to Server to get Records.

Everything working perfectly fine as expected. I am using this way of getting Records since two months..... Yesterday i just faced a strange issue,

I have two Internet Connections from differnt Vendors (internet supplier companies), when i just change my WiFi settings to access **SECOND** Internet Connection, **NSURLConnection Request is not receiving on Server and no Response in App**. I just put a break point in Testing phase and check all the code is compiling but with **nil** Respose.

I again change the WiFi settings to **FIRST** Internet Connection and **Again No Request sent to Server and NO Response**

```
One Important thing is that, In this testing Period Since Yesterday,
Three times the Request is sent to Server and I Got Response.
```

Why this all is happening, What may be the Problem...???

This is not the issue that may be No internet availability at that time. I am browsing and check all the time internet is Working perfectly.

**Today I just Quit XCode and Start again and using FIRST internet Connection, Now everything is working again perfectly as it should be.**

Again Question is what is the Problem here...???

This is the Code i am using to send Request and Get Response from Server.

```
NSString *message = @"XML Contains MySql Query";
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSURL *uRL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:uRL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSData *xmldata = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error: &error];

if (xmldata == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"response: %@", response);
        NSLog(@"error:    %@", error);
    }    
NSString *data = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmldata encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

this is the Response and Error i am receiving

```
response: (null)
error:    Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."    
UserInfo=0x7a6bafa0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http:/xxxxxxxx, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=57,
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xxxxx, NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost.,
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSUnderlyingError=0x7a7ddb80 "The network connection was lost."}
```

Comment: I notice that you are not providing an `error` variable on the `sendSynchronousRequest:` request and thus not reviewing the error. Add an `error` variable and `NSLog()` it when `xmldata` is `nil` then add the full error message to the question. Always check for errors and provide error variables.

Comment: @Zaph made Changes but Error is null in NSLog ....

Comment: @Zaph ... is this the right way of checking Erroe ...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the connection may be timing out ("The network connection was lost."): investigate that.

You might use Charles Proxy to look at the traffic, it will give you timing on the connection. Perhaps you could set a longer timeout or the server may have timeout limits.

I would investigate the connection times first and then that information might help me decide what to to next.

Previous:
It makes sense to obtain and examine return values when there are errors.

Example code:

```
NSError *error;
NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
NSData *xmldata = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (xmldata == nil) {
    NSLog(@"response: %@", response);
    NSLog(@"error:    %@", error);
}
```